# How to decode an array of JSON inside another array

Tags: json, swift, api, decoding

I'm playing around with tfl's api in swift, specifically the line status api but i'm having trouble decoding the `statusSeverityDescription` inside the nested object `lineStatuses`. Ideally, i'd like to retrieve the `name` of the line and the `statusSeverityDescription` together.

I'm able to correctly decode the `name` of the line from the JSON so i'm sure the problem is just a decoding error of the array.

here is the url for the api in question : https://api.tfl.gov.uk/line/mode/tube/status?detail=true

```
struct Line : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let lineStatuses : Status
}

struct Status : Decodable {
    let statusSeverityDescription : String

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case statusSeverityDescription = "statusSeverityDescription"
    }

    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        if let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self) {
            self.statusSeverityDescription = try! container.decode(String.self, forKey: .statusSeverityDescription)
        } else {
            let context = DecodingError.Context.init(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Unable to decode statuses!")
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context)
                }
    }

//this is in the UrlSession function

if let journey = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Line].self, from: data) 
        print(journey)
```

Comment: If you want to use Decodable https://app.quicktype.io is a great place to get all the structs you need to parse the returned json. It's especially useful if the json you're working with is complex. Just remember to review the autogenerated code before using it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lineStatuses` is an array so change its declaration in `Line` as below,

```
struct Line : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let lineStatuses : [Status]
}
```

Also you can omit `init` declaration in `Status` as,

```
struct Status : Decodable {

    let statusSeverityDescription : String
}
```

Comment: haha, thank you so much. i knew i was missing something small like that. but i just did't notice it.

Comment: just another quick quick question. how would i then print the statusSeverityDescription. i can print journey.name but it doesn't give me the option for statusSeverityDesciption

Comment: `journey.forEach { $0. lineStatuses.forEach{print($0.statusSeverityDescription)}}`  *OR*  `journey.forEach { print($0.lineStatuses.first?.statusSeverityDescription)}`